# Get list of values, then all post titles with that value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, meta-query

I have a working wordpress loop which displays all posts of a certain `meta_query` value. The only issue is that the values are repeated. For example, if I have two posts with the value "Blue" then both posts appear in the loop, which makes "Blue" appear twice.

What I would like is for "Blue" to appear once, and underneath it, a list of all post titles with that value.

Here's my current query:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_key'      => 'colors',
));

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

$colors = get_field('colors');

if( $colors ): foreach( $colors as $color ):  
    endforeach;
    endif; 
    echo' <div><h2>'.$color.'</h2><div>'.get_the_title( $post_id ).'</div></div>';

    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

I tried using an array for the titles, but it just returned "Array"

```
$titles = get_the_title();
$title_names = array();
foreach ($titles as $title){
$title_names[] = get_the_title($id);}
```

echo `$title_names`

I'm thinking I need another if statement somewhere with an array? Or maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to try something like this:

```
$results = [];
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    $the_query->the_post(); 
    $colors = get_field('colors');
    if( !empty($colors) ) {

        foreach( $colors as $color ) {  
            $results [$color][]['title'] = get_the_title();
            $results [$color][]['link'] = get_attachment_link();
        }

    }

}

foreach ($results as $color => $posts) {

    echo "<div><h2>{$color}<h2>";

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo "<div><a href=\"{$post['link']}">{$post['title']}</a></div>";
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I was looking for. If I want those titles to be links, such as `<a href="'.get_attachment_link($id).'">'.$post.'</a>` I would need another array, correct?

Comment: You could just use an associative array like how I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, for some reason `<a>` appears twice instead of wrapping around the title. It looks like this: `<div><a href="correct-url"></a><a href="">Title of Post</a><div>`

Comment: Not sure why it would be doing that. I would need to see your new code but it is probs a new question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll create a new post. Appreciate your help!

Comment: New post with answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404224/array-creates-duplicate-tags-wordpress/56404538#56404538